# i am trying to enter String until "stop", "Stop", "exit", or "Exit" is entered

Tags: java, string

i am creating a program for a computer Science class i am taking where the user may enter strings (as many as they would like) until the words "stop", "Stop", "exit", or "Exit" are entered. Also, when this one of those words are entered the program should enter the int stored in variable "wordcount" so that it may be printed to the console
showing the user the number of words they entered, NOT including the word used to stop the program. i am new to code and have no idea how to do this. here is my failed attempt:

```
package repeatWords;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RepeatWords {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         System.out.println("Enter words, type (stop or exit) to stop:");
         System.out.println();

         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         String word = keyboard.nextLine();
         int wordcount = 0;

         while(!(word.equals("exit")))
         {
             wordcount++;   
         }

         System.out.println("you enetered " + wordcount + "words.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Think about what separates words, and do a little research on the `split()` method for String.

Comment: Might want to look into the or(||) operator as well.

Comment: Do you need to keep adding a single word and check if stop/exit has been entered?

Comment: thank you both. unfortunately my instructor stated that we are not allowed to use methods we have not yet learned as sort of a challenge to complete the task either more efficiently or to learn how to complete the task using only what we have learned. however, i have learned about or(||) operator. it slipped my mind.

Comment: and yes ha9u63ar, i do have to have the program check for stop/exit.

Comment: I helps to think through your code one step at a time: talk to user, get user input, user enters "foo", wordcount is 0, word is "foo" (not "exit") so continue to loop, increment wordcount to 1, word is still "foo" so continue to loop, increment wordcount to 2, word is still "foo", wordcount to 3, word is still "foo", wordcount to 4........

Comment: the issue is that even when "exit" is entered by keyboard, the program doesn't terminate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only allowed to use what you have provided:

```
System.out.println("Enter words, type (stop or exit) to stop:");
System.out.println();

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String word = keyboard.nextLine();
int wordcount = 0;

while(!(word.equalsIgnoreCase("exit") || !word.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))) {
   word = keyboard.nextLine();
   wordcount++;   
}

System.out.println("you enetered " + wordcount + " word(s).");
```

The problem is you were stuck in an infinite loop because you never checked the `while` condition of the updated input of `word` from the scanner. This way, it will increment every time the user enters a new word, and then checks if the user has typed in a word that enables the loop to exit.

`equalsIgnoreCase()` will take your String value, and simply ignore the case sensitivity of its value. This will lessen your checks of 4 to 2.

Comment: No worries, and welcome to the awesome world of coding.